# Calculating Memory Usage of a Python Program

Tags: python, memory, memory-management

I'm trying to make a program that returns the memory usage of a Python program, a bit like on Leetcode when we submit a solution.

I looked up online and found three ways to do this, but all of them give really different answers when I try them on the same code, and I don't know why. Could someone explain what is the differences between them and which one does what I'm looking for?

```
#1) 
memoryUsage = (resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss)

#2) 
memoryUsage = psutil.Process(os.getpid())

#3) 
memoryUsage = tracemalloc.get_traced_memory()
```

I would also appreciate it if some could give an example of implementation, so I can know how to put the program and the function that is going to be tested.

Best regards.

Comment: This really isn't a programming question, but about the implementation details of some Python packages. You should read the source of those packages to learn how they work. If you're curious about memory management in general, I'd start with your OS's man pages.

Comment: Only the 1st call is related to the memory used by the process. The other ones are not. You have to read the documentation of teh respective functions.